# Is it possible to open files with a new window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to open files with a new window (Not splitting them into two tab in the same window)? Otherwise my second monitor will become useless.

Comment: use the File->New Window option in Visual Studio Code to open a second window, and then drag the file you want to view

Comment: could you move to the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**VSCode: Open file In a new Window:**

- File->New Window to open a second window,
- Drag the file you want to view to the second window

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3560f10e-cfdb-4a76-aeb3-52783d34db91/can-vscode-open-file-in-a-new-window?forum=vsarch

Comment: This will create a second VSCode instance. Here's a feature request for floating window support in a single VSCode instance: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10121

Answer (score 3):

If you have the file open you can use `ctl+k` `O` to open file in new window.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know when it was added but see:

```
"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on",
"window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on",
```

and [open recent files in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894206/visual-studio-code-open-recent-in-a-new-window/48894463#48894463)

Comment: I set Open Files in a new window to "default" and it seems to be doing what I want: in a project it opens in tabs, files clicked in the finder open in a new window. Lifestyle improvement!