# Visual Studio - Open Recent in a new Window

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any setting in Visual Studio such that when I do "open recent" it always open in a new window.
Right now it just opens it in the same window.

Comment: Ctrl-click will open a new window.

Comment: Can I set something that I don't have to do control+click? so configuration to make the control + click as the click. I don't want to remember that I have to press control key. Just use a new window always.

Comment: Cmd-click for mac as well

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
   "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on",
```

> Controls if files should open in a new window.
>
> - `default`: files will open in the window with the files' folder open or the last active window unless opened via the dock or from
>   finder (macOS only)
> - `on`: files will open in a new window
> - `off`: files will open in the window with the files' folder open or the last active window
>
> Note that there can still be cases where this setting is ignored (e.g. when using the `-new-window` or `-reuse-window` command line
> option).

```
  "window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on",
```

> Controls if folders should open in a new window or replace the last
> active window.
>
> - `default`: folders will open in a new window unless a folder is picked from within the application (e.g. via the File menu)
> - `on`: folders will open in a new window
> - `off`: folders will replace the last active window
>
> Note that there can still be cases where this setting is ignored (e.g.
> when using the `-new-window` or `-reuse-window` command line option).

Those should do the trick.  In your settings.json.

Comment: Where are these quotes from? Please add the source, preferably a link. Is it from your settings.json? These descriptions have been removed, IIUC. Also it looks like the formatting is a bit messed up, so please fix that too if possible. Like, `//` should start a line, right?

Answer (score 38):

Hold down **Control** before selecting if you don't wanna change the default settings.

Comment: And hold down **Shift** also works. Choose the one which is more intuitive to you.

Comment: @JohnnyWong holding down shift doesn't work for me at least.

Comment: @JohnnyWong I'm on windows 10 :), double tested again, using shift doesn't work on my machine!

Comment: Oh, just checked seems both "Shift" & "Ctrl" are not working in recent version 1.45.0 because of bug. (It has been working on 1.43.2 on Windows). BTW, they mentioned `@Dominik-K if you hold the Ctrl key or Shift key (macOS: Alt key or Cmd key) you can force open in a new window.` at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31581

Comment: Thanks. I think we may be talking about different "Open Recent". I meant the one in the Main Menu -> File -> Open Recent -> click an item with Shift/Ctrl. I guess you may mean the Ctrl-R popup, or the "Recent" section in the Welcome page, which both only support Ctrl-click to open new window there.

Comment: This feature stopped working in  v1.45.0. Neither **Shift** nor **Ctrl** are working on windows for me.

Comment: @Ali80  Both Open Recents Via Mian Menu and Ctrl+R doesn't work form me.

Comment: Info on 1.45.0's issue is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97237

Comment: The bug above has been fixed on 1.46.0 for Windows.

Answer (score 8):

On **macOS** possible to do like this:

1. Hold **⌘** (cmd) and pick one of the recent used project
2. Hold **ctrl** and **⎇** (alt) and pick one of the recent used project

Answer (score 0):

The settings offered in the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48894463) may be altered in the Visual Studio Code GUI by navigating to:

- Files --> Preferences --> Settings
- type "windows open" without the quote in the search bar
- in the results scroll down to
  Window: Open Files in New Window
  Window: Open Folders in New Window
  and set them to on from the dropdown selection as required.

In my case I wanted the File --> Open Recent to open a previous workspace. I elected to set just the  Window: Open Folders in New Window to on